# Passing address of array as a function parameter

Tags: c

Recently, I was debugging one of my programs and found a mistake that I've constantly make, but it was not shown as a warning during compilation, so I've just assume everything was in place and was OK. I a bit confused on what's happening in the code below:

```
void foo(char b[2]);
char a[2] = {1, 2};
foo(a);   // I always assumed that this would pass the entire array to be
          // duplicate in stack, guess I was wrong all this while
          // Instead the address of the array was passed

void foo(char b[2])
{
   // Value of b[0], b[1]?
   // Does this mean :   1) b[0] == &a[0]?
   //                or  2) b[0] == &a[0+2]?
   // Compiler didn't complain, so I assume this is a valid syntax
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you pass an array as a parameter to a function it decays into a pointer, this is defined in the C standard in `6.7.1`:

> On  entry   to  the  function    the  value  of  each  argument   expression   shall   be   converted    to  the  type 
>   of   its   corresponding     parameter,    as  if   by   assignment    to   the   parameter.     *Array    expressions*    and 
>   function    designators    as  arguments   are  *converted    to  pointers*    before   the  call.     A   declaration    of   a 
>   parameter    as  **“array     of   type”     shall   be  adjusted    to   “pointer      to   type,**”

This essentially means that in your function declaration it's equivalent to use

`void foo(char b[2]);` or
`void foo(char b[]);` or
`void foo(char *b)`

`

Comment: for foo(char b[2]), does this mean that I would be restricted to access for size of 2, e.g. b[0], b[1] is valid, but not b[2] and so on?

Comment: No, the actual value you put into brackets has no relevance.

Comment: To be more clear, you can call `f` with an array of chars of any size, and inside `f` you can access all valid positions in the array without issues, however, if you try to access positions beyond the actual size of your array you fall in undefined behaviour which means anything can happen.

Answer (score 0):

It is valid syntax, and yes, when passing an array the memory address of the first element is copied, but when you dereference the address, you are modifying the original array.

Answer (score 0):

This is the same as the following:

```
// The array "char b[2]" "decays" to a pointer "char *b"
void foo(char *b)
{
    // b[0] == a[0]
    // also, b == a (two addresses, both the same)
}
```

You can read up on how arrays and pointers in C behave very similarly (but not *exactly* the same).  Arrays decay to pointers if they're function arguments (but not anywhere else).  The real gotcha here is that on a 64-bit system, `sizeof(b) == 8` and `sizeof(a) == 2`, which is somewhat surprising unless you know about arrays decaying into pointers.

Answer (score 0):

1. When you declare an array as a function parameter, it is treated as if it were a pointer.  Your `foo` is completely identical to

   ```
   void foo(char *b)
   {
       ...
   }
   ```
2. Arrays decay to pointers.  In other words, in some uses (e.g. `sizeof(a)`) `a` is an array, but in others where a pointer is expected, the name `a` *means* the address of `a[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

`b[0] = &a[0]` if you do `foo(a)` as the argument.

If you pass `foo((a+1))` then `b[0] = &a[1]` (you shouldn't do that though since `b[1]` would be undefined) and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I should make a correction: the address of the array is not passed - it's the address of the array's first element. The simplest way of putting it is:

In C, the value of an array is a pointer to its first element.

If you work with arrays of arrays, you need to supply information about the sizes of arrays after the first dereference:

```
// either the following or: void foo(char param[][30][20])
void foo(char (*param)[30][20])
{
    // ...
}


int main(void)
{
    // bar is an array of 10 arrays of 30 arrays of 20 chars.
    // its value's TYPE is 'pointer to an array of 30 arrays of 20 chars,
    // which is what foo above requires.
    char bar[10][30][20];

    foo(bar);

}
```