# Sending an array to a function only sends the first element of the array

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, struct, mergesort

I have an array of the following struct

```
typedef struct monom {
    int coefficient; 
    int power;
}MONOM;
```

I have an array of monoms and I want to send it to a merge-sort function, when I do it, using the following call,

```
mergeSort(&polynomial, logSize);
```

only the first monom of the array of monoms is sent to the merge-sort function.

When I debug the function I see the full array on the line before the call to mergeSort but when I continue into mergeSort, only the first element is sent.

These are my mergeSort and merge, I'm completely clueless:

```
void mergeSort(MONOM** polynomial, int size)
{
    MONOM** res;
    int i;

    if (size < 2)
        return;

    else
    {
        mergeSort(*polynomial, size/2); // merge first half of array
        mergeSort(*polynomial+(size/2),size-(size/2)); // merge second half of array

        // allocate result array
        res = (MONOM**)malloc(size*sizeof(MONOM*));

        // merge both sorted halfs of the array into 'res'
        merge(*polynomial,size/2,*polynomial+(size/2),size-(size/2),res);

        // copy 'res' to 'arr'
        for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
            polynomial[i] = res[i];

        // release unused memory
        free(res);
    }
}

void merge(MONOM** poly1, int n1, MONOM** poly2, int n2, MONOM** res)
{
    int i1 = 0, i2 = 0;
    int resIndex = 0;

    while (i1 < n1 && i2 < n2)
    {
        if (poly1[i1]->power < poly2[i2]->power)
        {
            res[resIndex] = poly2[i2];
            i2++;
        }

        else if (poly1[i1]->power > poly2[i2]->power)
        {
            res[resIndex] = poly1[i1];
            i1++;
        }

        else
        {
            res[resIndex]->power = poly1[i1]->power;
            res[resIndex]->coefficient = poly1[i1]->coefficient + poly2[i2]->coefficient;
            i1++;
            i2++;
        }

        resIndex++;
    }

    // fill 'res' array when one of the arrays is finished
    while (i1 < n1)
    {
        res[resIndex] = poly1[i1];
        i1++;
        resIndex++;
    }

    while (i2 < n2)
    {
        res[resIndex] = poly2[i2];
        i2++;
        resIndex++;
    }
}
```

Comment: The first argument of `mergeSort()` is of type `MONOM **`. You're calling it recursively as `mergeSort(*polynomial, size/2)` - i. e. as its first argument, you pass in a `MONOM *`. What do you expect?

Comment: By the way, don't roll your own sorting algorithm, `qsort()` from `<stdlib.h>` works well.

Comment: Don't believe everything a debugger says.

Comment: @H2CO3 it's not the usual merge-sort, it also combines elements with the same power so I don't think any lib function will work

Comment: You might want to look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6645161/passing-address-of-array-as-a-function-parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

> mergeSort(polynomial, logSize); (Given polynomial is MONOM* or MONOM[] type)

and also

> void mergeSort(MONOM* polynomial, int size)

Comment: but I need polynomial to change, I must call it with an & don't I?

Comment: Not for an array, for an array by default it will change(without using _&_ operator). Using _&_ operator refers to the first element of the array(hence your problem)

Comment: You have to make many changes for your program. Eg, In some places you have dereferenced the pointer twice

Comment: @TheJoker No, the `&` operator refers to the entire array, and it yields a pointer-to-array type (of which the value can be the same as the pointer to the first element of the array, which the array decays into).

Comment: @H2CO3 While passing arrays as parameters isn't it a good idea not to use the _&_ operator?

Comment: @TheJoker It depends on what type the function takes :) Always pass a value of the expected type.

Comment: But isn't it very wasteful to send the entire array to the function instead of a pointer to the beginning of the array?

Comment: You are doing that by default. An array name always decays into pointer to the first element of the array.

Comment: @TheJoker: Not always.